# Find pytests tests that are not marked

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

We have a lot of tests in our project that it takes forever for it to complete in a single runner. So, I use pytest.mark to group the tests and in github actions I build a matrix based on these marks.
Problem is sometimes we forget to mark tests and they never run.
Is there a way to detect tests that do no have a mark? Maybe create a warning or error? I want to build a CI script that can detect this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to solve this.

```py
import argparse
import ast
import os
import re
import subprocess
from itertools import groupby

def get_test_lists(*args: str) -> list[str]:
    cmd = [
        "pytest",
        "--collect-only",
        "--disable-warnings",
        "--no-header",
        "--no-summary",
        "-q",
        "--color=no",
        "--capture=no",
        "-s",
        *args,
    ]
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, text=True, env=os.environ)
    test_paths_with_params: list[str] = [line for line in output.splitlines(False) if ".py" in line]

    filter_out = map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\[.*?\]", "", x), test_paths_with_params)

    test_paths: list[str] = list(set(filter_out))
    return sorted(test_paths)


def find_tests_without_mark(test_files: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    grouped_tests: dict[str, tuple[str, ...]] = {
        key: tuple(x.split("::", 1)[1] for x in group)
        for key, group in groupby(test_files, lambda x: x.split(".py", 1)[0] + ".py")
    }

    tests_without_mark: list[str] = []

    for file_path, test_functions in grouped_tests.items():
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            tree = ast.parse(file.read())
        for node in ast.walk(tree):
            # only for `test_*` function or `Test*` classes
            if (isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) and node.name in test_functions) or (
                isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef) and any(test.startswith(node.name) for test in test_functions)
            ):
                has_mark_decorator = False
                for decorator in node.decorator_list:
                    # does it have `pytest.mark.*`
                    has_mark_decorator = (
                        isinstance(decorator, ast.Attribute)
                        and isinstance(decorator.value, ast.Attribute)
                        and isinstance(decorator.value.value, ast.Name)
                        and decorator.value.value.id == "pytest"
                        and decorator.value.attr == "mark"
                    )
                    if has_mark_decorator:
                        break
                if not has_mark_decorator:
                    tests_without_mark.append(f"{file_path}::{node.name}")

    return tests_without_mark


test_files = get_test_lists("./")
tests_without_mark = find_tests_without_mark(test_files)
print(*tests_without_mark, sep="\n")
```